# how to cast string to float and store it into array of double type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, casting, double

I want to convert a string to double then store it into array of type double at the last, I did the following:

```
var num = "";
var sym = new Float64Array();

sym[sym.length] = parseFloat(num);
```

but when I prints the array I get `undefined` , so where is the wrong I did ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make necessary modfications. Refer [Float64Array API](http://www.javascripture.com/Float64Array)
.You define length in Float64array as a parameter.

your length is coming 1.

```
var num = "65";
var x = new Float64Array(1);
x[x.length-1] = parseFloat(num);
console.log(x[0]);
```

Comment: I got the value 0 stored into `x[0]` while the `num` value is 65

Comment: dint get you, can you please share the code. what you did on your side.

Comment: you can also make use of set method. var num = "65";
var x = new Float64Array(2);
x[0] = 0;
x.set([65],x.length-1)
console.log(x[1]);

Comment: Can you modfiy that fiddle a little bit and update your comment.

Comment: whatever the value the I entered into the array, all the values of the array are 0

Comment: your function clearScreen makes the length to 0. when are you calling it.

Comment: I didn't call the clearScreen, take a look at the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruE7d/2/)

Comment: var x = new Float64Array(10);
x[0] = 0;
console.log(x[0]);
console.log('Before x[1] ' +x[1]);
x[1] = 154;
console.log('After x[1] '+x[1]);
console.log(x.length);
Yes it will all be 0 because you are assigning one value of it to 0. at the same time you can modify rest of the array overrided with 0 value.

Comment: thank you very much, the error was in the function `expression()` , now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

`Float64Array`s can't grow and shrink like ordinary JS arrays. You have to allocate all the elements when creating it:

```
var sym = new Float64Array(10);
```

You can then assign elements:

```
sym[0] = 123.456;
console.log(sym);
> [123.456, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [];
var num = parseFloat("123.123")
arr.push(num);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You're not using `Float64Array`.